# simple cms for one page portfolio

Tags: looking-for-a-script, cms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I want to use a simple cms for a one page photography portfolio. 
Here are some screenshots of the website: [homepage](http://2.s3.envato.com/files/14125281/screenshots/screenshot-01.jpg)

and 
[interior page](http://3.s3.envato.com/files/14125281/screenshots/screenshot-012.jpg)

Basically I have just to insert a thumbnail image for index and a specific page for each thumbnail that contains a title a description and some images. 
I don't want to use Wordpress, I think is too much.
Could you recommend me some other cms for this type of portfolio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a one page portfolio. What you describe clearly uses many different pages. I'm also not sure what you mean by WordPress being "too much".

However, there *are* CMSes more appropriate for the style of website you described. Static CMSes designed for small sites offer more flexibility in site structure, though the more flexible/extensible ones require more manual editing and are much less user-friendly than WordPress, at least during the setup and initial learning curving.

Still, these might suit you better:

- [Subfolio](http://www.subfolio.com/)
- [Couch CMS](http://www.couchcms.com/)
- [Pulse](http://pulsecms.com/)
- [nanoc](http://nanoc.stoneship.org/)

Comment: I know visually isn't a one page portfolio but what I'm trying to say is that this website is Ajax driven and basically is just one page for editing

Answer (score -2):

You don't need any CMS for that you can use New HTNL 5 with jQuery to achieve this. Search Google for jQuery and you will find lot of resources.

Comment: Telling people to Google is not an answer. Provide links to actual resources. If you think the question's weak enough to dismiss, then just vote it down.